# Xamarin Android connect to Azure Notification Hub using Asp.Net core web api

Tags: android, asp.net, azure, xamarin, push-notification

I have Xamarin Forms Android project. It communicates restful with Asp.Net Core WebApi which is hosted on Azure. I need to be able to send Push messages using GCM and Azure Notification Hub. Sadly all documentations and sample which I could find are working with Azure Mobile Services but I need working sample with WebApi.
I'm new with this technologies and spanding more than a day. Please explain how to accomplish this or sharing code will be best.

Answer (score 1):

This is the documentation you need to use a hosted WebApi solution to send push notifications using Azure Notification Hub to Windows, iOS and Android.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification